# Brewing with Squash Guts

Tags: fermentation, techniques

So I'm very new at brewing and I'm looking to make a gift for my father. We have a small farm where we peel a lot of squash and cube it, leaving behind a lot of squash guts. I was wondering how I would go about making a sort of squash gut liqueur? Any amount of advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This might be more appropriate over at https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

Liqueurs tend to be high in alcohol and thus produced by distillation and maybe subsequent infusion. That is not a topic we generally advise on here. However sweet squash guts may well be a good source of sugars for fermenting - especially if an amylase is added to break down the bigger carbs.
Apart from liqueur, Pumpkins can form part of a beer recipe. Pumpkin ales tend to be made with malt with pumpkin flesh added in the ferment - in effect pumpkin flavoured beer. It is possible to ferment pumpkin mash on its own but it tends to be a messy process and when I tasted the resulting ferment it was a bit slimy. So I rarely recommend fermenting pure pumpkin without further processing. YMMV

Comment: Hubbard squash, for example, can be substituted for pumpkin.

Comment: I accept pumpkin/squash can be fermented. Its just that pumpkin/squash gut aren't so useful in the same role. However I do approve of the infusion idea given by farmersteve below. But again -not using squash guts but the lightly roasted flesh of the squash.The flesh of the squash is full of carbs and with an amylase could be mashed and fermented like any brew. Then distill it. The "guts and seed surrounding tissue is not particularly rich in sugars or carbs.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make a Squash liqueur it's pretty simple. Roast some squash until soft, then add it too a jar and top up with some vodka and sugar and spices. Let it around for a couple of weeks, then drink. I found several recipes using google.

Here is a good [recipe](https://www.kitchenkonfidence.com/2012/11/butternut-squash-five-spice-liqueur)

INGREDIENTS

- 3 to 4 pound butternut squash
- Good quality vodka
- 1 cup white sugar
- 1 cup packed light brown sugar
- 5 whole star anise
- 1 cinnamon stick, broken into smaller pieces
- 1 tablespoon fennel seeds
- 1 tablespoon black peppercorns
- 1 teaspoon whole cloves
- 2 cups water

INSTRUCTIONS
Preheat oven to 350 degrees F.

1. Peel butternut squash, cut in half lengthwise, then clean out seeds and guts.
2. Discard skin, seeds and guts. Cut the squash up into 1.5-inch chunks. Spread out in an even layer on a parchment-lined baking sheet. Bake until it is tender (test by inserting the tip of a knife), 20 – 30 minutes. Do not overcook here. The squash should be tender, but not falling apart. Let the squash cool to room temperature, then transfer to a large mason jar.
3. Add vodka to the jar until it covers the squash by 1 inch (I used between 750 ml and 1 L). Seal the jar and store in a cool, dark spot.
4. Give the jar a gentle shake every few days. Start tasting the vodka after 1 week. The finished infusion should taste very strongly of butternut squash. I was pleased with the flavor after 2 weeks; however, this can vary based on taste.
5. Once you are satisfied with the butternut squash flavor, pour the mixture through a medium-mesh basket strainer into a clean bowl or jar. Discard the solids. Strain again through a fine-mesh strainer into another clean bowl or jar. Set aside while you prepare the 5-Spice Syrup.
6. In small saucepan, combine sugars, spices and water. Bring mixture to a boil over medium-high heat, stirring to dissolve the sugar. Once the mixture comes to a boil, drop the heat to low, and simmer for 5 minutes. Let the mixture cool completely, then strain out all of the spices. Discard spices.
7. Pour syrup into the infused vodka, stirring to combine. Cover and let rest for 1 more day before serving.